# Find and extract data from a text file

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, fstream

I'm tring to search a text file and extract the data after a heading.  However, I've got some issues with iterators that I don't know how to overcome.

This is a sample text file:

> ```
> Relay States
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> ```

Ideally, I'd like to call `LoadData<bool> something.LoadData("Relay States");` and have it return an std::vector with {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...}.

```
template<typename T> std::vector<T> CProfile::LoadData(const std::string& name)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(FILE_NAME);
    std::vector<T> data;
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> iit = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs);

    std::search(iit, ifs.eof(), name.begin(), name.end());
    std::advance(iit, name.size() + 1);

    T buffer = 0;
    for(ifs.seekg(iit); ifs.peek() != '\n' && !ifs.eof(); data.push_back(ifs))
    {
        ifs >> buffer;
        data.push_back(buffer);
    }

    return data;
}
```

From what I understand, the main problems with my code are:

- std::search is an ambiguous call, how would I go about fixing this?
- ifs.seekg(iit) is not legal, how would I go about making iit a valid argument?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the headers and data always on separate lines? Is the data on separate lines like in the sample you shown? Is the amount of data always the same, or how do you keep track of how much it is?

Comment: If the data comes from a 2D array, then it's exactly as above.  To work out how much to download, I must read between the heading name, and "\n\n".  After the data, there are always two \n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think your args to std::search is problem

```
std::search(iit, ifs.eof(), name.begin(), name.end());
```

should be

```
std::search(iit, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), name.begin(), name.end());
```

as for line :  `ifs.seekg(iit)` in `for` loop isn't good , since seekg expects some offset of type `streampos` not an iterator. so it should be `ifs.seekg(0)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Do you know how I could set the offset to the char to which iit points?

Comment: @user968243 `iit` is istream buffer iterator which takes the bytes from `istream`'s buffer internally (so when you advance the `iit` by `name.size() + 1` it reads that much bytes from `istream`'s buffer) , It doesn't have any position actually. From seeing your code ,I can say `iit` gets advanced by `name.size() + 1` (so it's currently at byte at `name.size() + 1` ) , so you can do `ifs.seekg(name.size() + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
template<typename T> std::vector<T> CProfile::RealLoadData(std::istream &is)
{
    std::string line;
    std::vector<T> data;

    while (std::getline(is, line))
    {
        if (line.empty())
            break;  // Empty line, end of data

        std::istringstream iss(line);

        T temp;
        while (iss >> temp)
            data.push_back(temp);
    }

    return data;
}

template<typename T> std::vector<T> CProfile::LoadData(const std::string& name)
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream ifs(FILE_NAME);

    while (std::getline(ifs, line))
    {
        if (line == name)
        {
            // Found the section, now get the actual data
            return RealLoadData<T>(ifs);
        }
    }

    // Section not found, return an empty vector
    return std::vector<T>();
}
```